# FB api , can album created via app be also deleted by the app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Created albm via app, and then tried to delete it via this code:

```
 public function delete_album($id)
{
            /* make the API call */
    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $this->session,
      'DELETE',
      '/'.$id
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
    /* handle the result */
}
```

but error shows:

```
'(#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.'
```

i have 'publish_actions' permission...what else i need or is it not possible to delete album even though its created via same app?

Comment: The documentation say that you can't: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/album

Comment: yes i did read that too, i just hoped , cuz i did read on some 2 year old post that you can delete albums that are created by your app , but yeah, i guess its just not possible, thankz anyway